# Comments change the template name

Tags: comments

I am following this tutorial: https://www.wpthemedetector.com/create-archives-page/

How come when I type the following block of code in a file named page-archives.php, the template name changes? For example, if I typed in "Archive2" the dropdown list would display Archive2. **I thought comments didn't have any effect.**

```
<?php

/*
Template Name: Archives
*/

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That comment is what makes a file as a (custom) page template. Relevant excerpt from [Creating Custom Page Templates for Global Use](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use):

> To create a global template, write an opening PHP comment at the top
>   of the file that states the template’s name.
>
> ```
> <?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
> ```

And the [tutorial](https://www.wpthemedetector.com/create-archives-page/) actually says, "the name of the template that appears in the Page Attributes section of the WordPress page editor is defined using the *Template Name* string".

So, whatever name you define there would be the name used in the templates dropdown. E.g. `Template Name: Archive2` would assign the template name to `Archive2`.